# Cassandra queries are timing out, taking consistency as ALL when explicitly specified as LOCAL_QUORUM

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra queries are timing out for select query:

```
SELECT x, y FROM <table> WHERE unique_id= <value>
```

with the exception

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency ALL (3 responses were required but only 2 replica responded)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.copy(ReadTimeoutException.java:88)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.copy(ReadTimeoutException.java:25)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
```

Cassandra Driver :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Our query code :

```
    QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
    queryOptions.setSerialConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_SERIAL);
    queryOptions.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM);

    List<String> contactPoints = Utils
        .getArrayStrings(config, Constants.CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS);

    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
        .addContactPoints(contactPoints.toArray(new String[contactPoints.size()]))
        .withQueryOptions(queryOptions)
        .withProtocolVersion(ProtocolVersion.V4)
        .build();

    Session session = cluster.connect();
    session.executeAsync(SELECT_STATEMENT).bind()
                .setUUID(0, UUID.fromString(inputEvent.getUniqueId()))
```

Why is it taking consistency as ALL, when we have set explicitly set in query options consistency as LOCAL_QUORUM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks very like [CASSANDRA-7947](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7947), where if timeout happens in query that triggered read repair (that is executed with `ALL`), then the reported as `ALL` instead of original `LOCAL_QUORUM`.  Although this bug should be already fixed in  2.0.12/2.1.3...

Comment: Cassandra version I am using is 3.0.14.10

Comment: I think that I have seen an error recently that was related to read repair, but not read repair itself...

Answer (score 2):

We ran into the same issue in our production environment. It looks like it is related with the read repair process described in here [CASSANDRA-10726](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10726). Also in this duplicate [CASSANDRA-14480](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14480) bug other people are having the exact behavior.

We noticed this error only after we switched to a multi DC environment.

We are using this versions:

Cassandra: 3.0.15
DSE: 5.0.12
Java Driver: 3.1.4